# Static html page created the WebSocket connection golang server directly

Tags: sockets, websocket, go

I'm writing an `html` page that needs to create a `websocket` to the server

On the server, I used the example in "code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket" just accept the connection.

However, in Chrome26 the response is

**WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:1234/' failed: Unexpected response code: 400**

Is there something is missed (like a handshake)?

This is my `html` and server is using `go`

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sock = null;
    var wsuri = "ws://127.0.0.1:1234";

    window.onload = function() {

        console.log("onload");

        sock = new WebSocket(wsuri);

        sock.onopen = function() {
            console.log("connected to " + wsuri);
        }

        sock.onclose = function(e) {
            console.log("connection closed (" + e.code + ")");
        }

        sock.onmessage = function(e) {
            console.log("message received: " + e.data);
        }
    };

    function send() {
        var msg = document.getElementById('message').value;
        sock.send(msg);
    };
</script>
<h1>WebSocket Echo Test</h1>
<form>
    <p>
        Message: <input id="message" type="text" value="Hello, world!">
    </p>
</form>
<button onclick="send();">Send Message</button>
</body>
</html>
```

//------------------------------

```
package main

import (
    "code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func Echo(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    var err error

    for {
        var reply string

        if err = websocket.Message.Receive(ws, &reply); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Can't receive")
            break
        }

        fmt.Println("Received back from client: " + reply)

        msg := "Received:  " + reply
        fmt.Println("Sending to client: " + msg)

        if err = websocket.Message.Send(ws, msg); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Can't send")
            break
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", websocket.Handler(Echo))
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":1234", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe:", err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome is likely throwing error 400 because it thinks you are trying to do a cross-domain request to the websocket server and thinks it is unlikely you have permission.

To solve the issue you simply have to server your html from your `go`-server too.

So change your `sock.go` code to:

```
package main

import (
    "code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func Echo(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    var err error

    for {
        var reply string

        if err = websocket.Message.Receive(ws, &reply); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Can't receive")
            break
        }

        fmt.Println("Received back from client: " + reply)

        msg := "Received:  " + reply
        fmt.Println("Sending to client: " + msg)

        if err = websocket.Message.Send(ws, msg); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Can't send")
            break
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("."))) // <-- note this line
    http.Handle("/socket", websocket.Handler(Echo))
    log.Println("serving")
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":1234", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe:", err)
    }
}
```

and add your `index.html` file to the same directory as your sock.go file:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sock = null;
    var wsuri = "ws://127.0.0.1:1234/socket"; // <-- note new path

    window.onload = function() {

        console.log("onload");

        sock = new WebSocket(wsuri);

        sock.onopen = function() {
            console.log("connected to " + wsuri);
        }

        sock.onclose = function(e) {
            console.log("connection closed (" + e.code + ")");
        }

        sock.onmessage = function(e) {
            console.log("message received: " + e.data);
        }
    };

    function send() {
        var msg = document.getElementById('message').value;
        sock.send(msg);
    };
</script>
<h1>WebSocket Echo Test</h1>
<form>
    <p>
        Message: <input id="message" type="text" value="Hello, world!">
    </p>
</form>
<button onclick="send();">Send Message</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Now you will be able to connect from within chrome.

Comment: but i do not want to deal the protocol by myself did not the golang has deal this?

Comment: This is not 'dealing the protocol'  per-ce, more dealing with the browser. I've updated your code for you to add a filehandler. You will not be able to connect if you load your file from the filesystem you must load the file over http prefereably from the same origin.

Comment: Actually I had test other language to make the server like  java netty，c# they all support to accept the html create the websocket that no in server ,it just a html anyever , i think there is a tab in the protocol like "original" was miss becasue the html was local ,and the golang websocket just refuse this

Comment: i found somebody deal the protocol by himself make this possible https://github.com/garyburd/go-websocket/tree/master/websocket

Comment: I would like to add that the Go webserver does not accept sockets that do not have a origin in their request. Opening a html file from explorer with some JS will result in the webserver returning a unexpected result: 403